# Micro don't work with headset set on A2DP

Tags: a2dp

Using headset bluetooth on Ubuntu 22.04. With A2DP profile used, micro don't work, even with audio input checked in settings. How to enable micro with A2DP profile? With HSP profile, micro work, but I don't want to use HSP because the sound quality is very ugly.